# Setting a cookie for HTTP POST in Scala with Dispatch

Tags: scala, post, cookies, scala-dispatch

I can't seem to set a cookie using Dispatch. The server resends a new session ID implying that the one I tried to send didn't get sent in the right way. Here is the code:

```
val domain = "myhost.com"
val host_req = host(domain).secure
val request = host_req / "path" / "path"

def post = request << Map("key" -> "SomeValue")

val response: Either[Throwable, Map[String, String]] =
    Http(post OK asHeaders).either()

//The cookie comes down in the form "Set-Cookie: SESSIONID=<somesession>; Path=/path/; HttpOnly"

//successfully retrieves the session id...
val sessionId = getSessionId(response)
println(sessionId)
val sessionCookie = new com.ning.http.client.Cookie(domain, "SESSIONID", sessionId, "/path/", -1, true)

request.POST.addCookie(sessionCookie)
def establishPost = request << Map("key" -> "SomeValue")
establishPost.addCookie(sessionCookie)

val establishResponse: Either[Throwable, Map[String, String]] =
    Http(establishPost OK asHeaders).either()


//Server sends down new SESSIONID...
//sessionId != getSEssionId(establishPost)
```

This is using the newest version of Dispatch. I'm trying to learn Scala as I go, and the only thing I can't figure out how to do either is inspect the establishPost object for its headers before it is sent as a request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be better:

```
def reqWithParams = request << Map("key" -> "SomeValue")
val reqWithCookies = reqWithParams.addCookie(sessionCookie)
```

addCookie method returns the new object (the one with a cookie), but your code didn't use it.

Comment: This seems to be the problem with setting the cookie for sure. Can you answer the 2nd part as to how I would inspect the content of the POST request so I can compare it to a known valid POST?

Comment: This definitely fixes the problem.

Comment: Regarding inspecting the request object: the easiest would be just to print it out in your log. It has the following methods defined: host, creds, method, path, headers, body, defaultCharset. body is of type `Option[org.apache.http.HttpEntity]` and headers is `List[(String, String)]`. I would recommend downloading dispatch distro from github: https://github.com/dispatch/dispatch and inspecting the code, it's definitely enlightening :)

Comment: I finally have some intellisense after remaking the eclipse project w/ sbt. The problem I had was doing println(mypost) yielded "Req(<function1>)". Intellisense showed me a method toRequest() which I could then do println(mypost.toRequest) and it showed something useful then.

Comment: Fake it until you make it :) it's very confusing at the beginning, just give it a couple of months and keep reading and trying to understand the code other people wrote, you'll get better :)